# The right way to connect to query database mongodb multiples times

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

im building a website in my free time using nodejs/Handlebars.js/mongodb(mongoose),
i didnt study any web developement lessons, and i dont know  the right way to do things efficiently and securely.
so in this project, i stumbled upon a problem where i had to query in the database if email already exists or no if it does, it queries again if the username already exists or not, if it does exists the user can be registred to the databse. yes it gets the job done but im not satisfyied with this approach, it seems to be unprofessional and not secure.
so can you please tell me the right way to do it ?

**this is the part where i think i ve done it the wrong way**

```js
 //check for errors in Req.validation and push them to errors Array
if(valErrors){
 for (var i = 0; i < valErrors.length; i++) {
   errors.push(valErrors[i])
 }
}
//check if the username submitted exists in the database 
User.findOne({'username':username}, function (err, user) {  
 if(user)
  {
   errors.push({msg:"username is already in use!"})    
   res.render('user/register',{
    errors:errors
   });
  }
        //if the username is not in use already check if the email is in 
        //use 
  else {
   User.findOne({'email':email}, function (err, user) {
    if(user){
     errors.push({msg:'email is already in use !'})  
     res.render('user/register',{
      errors:errors
     });   
    } //if the email doesnt exists too then register this //user
    else{
     var coins = new Coins()
     var newUser = new User({
     name: name,
     email:email,
     username: username,
     password: password,
     coins:coins.encryptcoins('0'),
     joindate:getDate()
     });

     User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;  
     });
     req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');
     res.redirect('/user/login');
     } 
    

   });
  }
});
  
})
```

**EDIT:**
**user Schema**

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 username: {
  type: String,
  index:true,
  required:true
 },
 password: {
  type: String,
  required:true
 },
 email: {
  type: String,
  required:true
 },
 name: {
  type: String,
  required:true
 },
 coins: {
  type:String,
  required:true
 },
 joindate: {
  type:String,
  required:true
 },
 orders: {
  type:Array,
  required:false
 }
},{collection:'Users'});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
 bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
     bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
         newUser.password = hash;
         newUser.save(callback);
     });
 });

}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
 var query = {username: username};
 User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
 User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
 bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
     if(err) throw err;
     callback(null, isMatch);
 });
}
```

**this is the whole code**

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/users');
const ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn();
const ensureLoggedOut = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedOut();
var Coins = require('../models/coins');
// Register
router.get('/register',ensureLoggedOut, function(req, res){
 res.render('user/register');
});

// Login
router.get('/login',ensureLoggedOut, function(req, res){
 res.render('user/login');
});

// Register User
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
 var name = req.body.name;
 var email = req.body.email;
 var username = req.body.username;
 var password = req.body.password;
 var password2 = req.body.password2;

 console.log(email)
 console.log(username)
 // Validation
 req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
 req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
 req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

 //Error handling
 var errors = [];
 var valErrors = req.validationErrors()
 //check for errors in Req.validation and push them to errors Array
 if(valErrors){
  for (var i = 0; i < valErrors.length; i++) {
    errors.push(valErrors[i])
  }
 }
    //check if the username submitted exists in the database 
 User.findOne({'username':username}, function (err, user) {  
  if(user)
   {
    errors.push({msg:"username is already in use!"})    
    res.render('user/register',{
     errors:errors
    });
   }
            //if the username is not in use already check if the email is in 
            //use 
   else {
    User.findOne({'email':email}, function (err, user) {
     if(user){
      errors.push({msg:'email is already in use !'})  
      res.render('user/register',{
       errors:errors
      });   
     } //if the email doesnt exists too then register this //user
     else{
      var coins = new Coins()
      var newUser = new User({
      name: name,
      email:email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      coins:coins.encryptcoins('0'),
      joindate:getDate()
      });

      User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
       if(err) throw err;  
      });
      req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');
      res.redirect('/user/login');
      } 
     

    });
   }
 });
   
})


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
 function(username, password, done) {
  User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
   if(err) throw err;
   if(!user){
    return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
   }

   User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(isMatch){
     return done(null, user);

    } else {
     return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
    }
   });
  });
 }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
 done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
 User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
  done(err, user);
 });
});

router.post('/login',
 passport.authenticate('local', {successReturnToOrRedirect: '/', failureRedirect:'/user/login',failureFlash: true}),
 function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
 });

router.get('/logout',ensureLoggedIn, function(req, res){
 req.logout();
 req.session.destroy();
 res.redirect('/');

});

module.exports = router;








function getDate(){
 var d = new Date()
 return ("date: "+d.getDate()+"/"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"/" +d.getFullYear() + " time GMT+1: "+(d.getHours()+1)+":"+(d.getMinutes())).toString()
}









// replaced with Ensure loging in library !
// function ensureLoggedIn(req, res, next) { 
//   if(req.user){
//     return next()
//   }else{
//     res.redirect('/user/login');
//   }
// }
// function ensureLoggedOut(req, res, next) { 
//   if(!req.user){
//     return next()
//   }else{
//     res.redirect('/');
//   }
// }
```

Comment: Can you please post the schema of your database? Your data look relational, thus, I don't see a reason of using MongoDB over a RDBMS.

Comment: sure , i posted the User Schema  and what  s the diffrence between RDBMS and mongoDB ?

Comment: Well, since your schema is in a normalized form (i.e., no nested fields), an RDBMS might yield better performance in your scale (i assume you're want to handle up to 1000 transactions per second and don't have additional tables). MongoDB would offer additional functionality and performance if you wanted to scale out in more than one nodes and make use of nested types (like JSON).

Comment: okay thanks but i think i will go with mongodb(mongoose). so there is not problem with the method i used ?

Comment: Sounds good. I will make a number of suggestions based on "sound" database usage principles, and I am sure that you can figure out the syntax. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for a logical unit of work send to a Database Management System (DBMS) (i.e., MongoDB server), it is imperative to group the individual operations in a single transaction. This way, you can avoid inconsistencies that might result from concurrent user creation in your database.

To be more precise, in your project the registration process checks for the following:

1. Check if email exists
2. Check if username exists
3. If queries 1 and 2 returned an empty result set, register a new user

In essence, those 3 steps need to take place in an atomic fashion, which means that they occur as a single logical unit (Transaction). If not, in the extreme case that 2 concurrent clients try to register users with the same usernames, then your database will result with two users with the same username.

Therefore, you should update your code to do the following:

1. Initiate a transaction
2. Check for users with the given email (`user_email`) and or usernamae (`user_name`)
3. If the query of step 2 returned a user, then rollback the transaction; Otherwise, insert a new user with `user_email` and `user_name`.
4. Commit Transaction

I am not sure whether MongoDB supports Transactional Consistency, and this is one of the reasons that I suggested using an RDBMS. Also, if it doesn't, I am sure that you can figure out a schema that identifies a single user based on email/username and try to perform the registration as a transaction.

Finally, it is considered good practice to have most of the processing take place in the DBMS side with the use of Stored Procedures.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you it helps and yes , that s what i really want to do. i tried to make two functions one to check for email and return true if it exists or false if it doesnt and the other function to do the same for username, and then proceed to registration. However, the results was a bit wierd. since nodejs is asynchronous and  it takes time to query both username and email,the two functions returns null in the if statement, because they didnt complete the quering.

Comment: I am glad I helped. Please, mark my post as an answer so that the question is marked as closed.